# fosuserbundle relation with another table whish the foreign key should be initialized

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, many-to-one

my class User(mynamespace/userbundle/user) extend the fos/userbundle/Entity/user .

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups=     {"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max="255",
 *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
protected $prenom;
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Profile")
 *
 */
protected $profile;

//getters and setters
....
```

my class user has an attribut $profile . the profile is a class that owns two attributs :

```
class Profile
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $libel;
//getters and setters
 ....
```

in my database i have the foreign key(profile_id) in my user table references to the table Profile .
what i want is when i register a new user , i want to set a default value for profile_id . 
i search about this problem . i found that i have to implement the Registrationcontroller but i don't know what to add . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2.0 version of FosUserBundle, IMHO it's better to use events listeners. In this case have a look at [Hooking into the controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md).

If you use old version, follow this guide: [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md).